# Why can't i chain the .map() function on observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm having difficulties understanding why i can't chain .map() functions on the callback of a get request.

```
const random = max => Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
this._http.get('https://unsplash.it/list')
    .map(response => response.json())
    .map(metaImages => metaImages.url_post)
    .subscribe(urls => {
        this.imgSrc = urls[random(urls.length)];
    });
```

So i break it down like this

```
const random = max => Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
this._http.get('https://unsplash.it/list')
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(metaImages => {
        const urls = metaImages.map(url => url.post_url);
        this.imgSrc = urls[random(urls.length)];
    });
```

But why exactly is this? Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Just to make sure, why can the first .map() transform the response object to a json object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you don't confuse mapping an observable, which maps the observable emission stream, with mapping an array, which maps elements in the array. In your case, if you want to map at the observable level before subscribing, your observable map must do an array mapping of the emission.

```
const random = max => Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
this._http.get('https://unsplash.it/list')
    .map(response => response.json())

    .map(metaImages => metaImages.map(url => url.post_url))
     ^^^ MAP EMITTED ARRAY        ^^^ MAP ELTS IN EMITTED ARRAY

    .subscribe(urls => this.imgSrc = urls[random(urls.length)]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and clear explanation! @torazaburo